# How to get attribute of tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if my question was stupid. please someone one tell me how to do this following issue. I have tags like shown below

```
<link rel="next" href="#" >
<link rel="prev" href="#" >
```

now i need to select this tag by using where rel has next and where tag rel has prev eg: `rel="next"`

```
getElementbyAttribute(rel="next").href ="www.yyyy.com"

getElementbyAttribute(rel="prev").href ="www.mmmm.com"
```

How to do this in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` to get all of the matching elements:

```
document.querySelector("[rel='next']");
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("[rel='next']").setAttribute("href", "bbb.com");`